# How to use always newest cookbook while some other keep locking with Berkshelf

Tags: chef-infra, berkshelf

I have a `Berksfile` like this:

```
source "https://api.berkshelf.com"

cookbook 'ruby_build'
cookbook 'rbenv', github: 'fnichol/chef-rbenv'
cookbook 'foo', git: 'git@bitbucket.org:ironsand/cookbook-foo.git'
```

After `knife solo cook node`, `Berksfile.lock` is created and lock the version of cookbooks.

I want to use latest cookbook for own cookbook(`foo`), and lock the version for cookbook created by others(`rbenv`,`ruby_build`).

I couldn't find out how to do it. does anyone know can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can specify your cookbook versions in the Berksfile.  Or, in the case of the cookbooks that you are giving a git repo for, you can specify the revision to pull.

```
source "https://api.berkshelf.com"

cookbook 'ruby_build', '= 4.0.2'
cookbook 'rbenv', github: 'fnichol/chef-rbenv', tag: 'some_Tag'
cookbook 'foo', git: 'git@bitbucket.org:ironsand/cookbook-foo.git', :branch 'master'
```

you can also use `:ref 'some_git_hash_for_ref'` at if you want a specific hash rather than a tag or branch.

Comment: Maybe I'm understanding wrongly, but even if I specify a git repo and branch or tag, the revision is locked by `Berksfile.lock` when I run `knife solo cook` command. So the latest revision are not used until I remove `Berksfile.lock`.

Comment: yes, that's why it is a `.lock` file.  If you want to update a version, you must run `berks update` or remove the lock file.

Comment: That is my question, how to free from `.lock` my own repositories while keep locking other repositories.

Comment: If you lock down the versions you want in your Berksfile, and then delete the Berksfile.lock before running `knife solo`, you should be fine.  The specific versions in Berksfile will get honored, and the cookbooks that don't have a specific version in Berksfile will use the latest compatible.